# display on the calendar (in a different color) whether or not a timesheet has been received for a certain day

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm designing a shift calendar for our employees.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Shift` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`accountId` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
`grpId` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
`locationId` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
`unitId` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
`shiftTypeId` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
`startDate` date NOT NULL,
`endDate` date NOT NULL,
`needFlt` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1',
`needBillet` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1',
`fltArr` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`fltDep` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`fltArrMade` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
`fltDepMade` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
`billetArrMade` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
`billetDepMade` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
`FacilityId` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
`FacilityWingId` mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
`FacilityRoomId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`comment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`creation` datetime NOT NULL,
`lastUpdate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`lastUpdateBy` mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I'd like to be able to display on the calendar (in a different color) whether or not a timesheet has been received for a certain day.

I could create a separate table and list separate entries by day for each employee, T/F.  But the amount of data returned from a separate query, for each employee, for the whole month would be huge and inefficient.

I could put the information in this Shift table, with delimiters - then exploding it with PHP.  Silly idea.

Comment: You could serialize (http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), but that's just like creating an embedded table in a cell. Are you sure you want to wrap all that kind of instance data in with your object data? What's the benefit?

Comment: So, the calander would be shown for 1 employee at a time? And the records in the 'Shift' table can span multiple days?

Comment: The shift calendar would be displaying all employees in a certain department vertically extending horizontally by date.  So that would be a ton of rows returned (~20) for each employee's timesheet data, just to color the calendar a different color for a certain day.

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re how you are 1st stuck? "efficient" means nothing in particular so after you tell us what you mean by it, how you are stuck evaluating by that criterion? [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461) Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help] Clarify via edits, not comments. Delete & flag obsolete comments. Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts.

Answer (score 1):

As hinted previously and I think you realized yourself, serializing the data into a single column or using some other form of delimited string is a path to computational inefficiencies in the packing and unpacking and serious maintenance grief for the future.

Heaps better is to get the data structure right, i.e. a properly normalized table. After all, MySQL is rather good at dealing with this some of structure.

You don't need to pull back every line for every staff member. If you're pull them out together, you could "group" your resultset by employee and date, and even make that a potentially useful result by (say) pulling the summary of hours. A zero result or null result would show no timesheet, and the total hours may be helpful in some other way.

If you were pulling them out an employee and a date at a time then your application structure probably needs looking at, but you could use the SQL LIMIT keyword to pull at most one record and then test to see if any came back.

Comment: A less complicated solution would be to create an object for each day of the month for the employee.  But that doesn't sound too efficient when we're talking about 100 employees... let alone scalability for other companies to use.